# Macbook does not recognise bootable usb disk carrying 'Lubuntu 14.04.1 desktop amd64-mac.iso'

Tags: 14.04, boot, live-usb, macbook

i want to install **lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64+mac**
on a **macbook 3.1** that currently has ubuntu 17.04.

i created a **bootable usb** (sandisk 16GB) using **start up disk creator** on a dell inspiron that runs ubuntu 16.04. i checked the usb on the dell and it booted just fine. i tried lubuntu without installing it.

i did the exact same thing on another usb (kingston 1GB) and again checked it out on the dell. worked fine too

when i plug either usb drive on the macbook and boot holding the 'option' key down i end up on a **'boot menu'** screen with only a 'windows' named hard drive as an option...

any ideas why the macbook refuses to 'see' the usb disks???

thanks a lot

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't fit in a 1GB stick so that couldn't possibly work.

Comment: 14.04 lubuntu fits in a 1Gb disk... the image is around 720MB. but as i wrote i used two usb disks the other being 16GB and both were succesfully booted from on the dell inspiron...